# Backbone.js view of model containing collection?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

In my Backbone.js app I have a Model that contains a Collection. To support fetching that model from the back end I override the parse method to transform the array in the JSON response to a collection instance. It looks something like this:

```
class SomeModel extends Backbone.Model
  defaults: ->
    collection: new SomeCollection([new SomeModel(attr: value)])

  parse: (res) ->
    res.collection = new SomeCollection(res.collection)
    res

class SomeCollection extends Backbone.Collection
  model: SomeOtherModel

class SomeCollectionView extends Backbone.View
  el: $('collection-view')
```

My problems is that while `SomeCollectionView` is bound to an existing instance of `SomeCollection`, when calling `SomeModel.fetch()` that instance is replaced and the view is no longer valid. I *could* call `remove()` on the old view and instantiate a new one but my `SomeCollectionView` is layered on top of existing HTML (not built from a template) and calling remove pulls out the element from the DOM. Moreover, I would much prefer if my view could simply react to a change event rather than requiring reconstruction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did stuff like you said (collection in model) from different "side" which would work here. When I had a model that had a Collection I used events in the model to create collection.

```
class ModelA extends Backbone.Model
  initialize: ->
    bind("change", @initializeCollection)

  initializeCollection: ->
    if !@collection
      @collection = new Collection(@attributes.collection) 
    else
      @collection.set(@attributes.collection)
```

The rest is the same so I won't put it in.

Also if you go deeper: 
modelA -> collecionB -> modelB -> collectionC -> modelC
Than in modelB in constructor you can create collectionC (providing you don't reuse it)

[Edit]
I've got another idea:

```
class ModelA extends Backbone.Model
  parse: (resp) ->
    if @attributes.collection
      @attributes.collection.set(resp.collection)
      delete resp.collection
    else
      resp.collection = new Collection(resp.collection)
    resp
```

Comment: Neat. The downside to this approach, however, is that you cannot call `model.get('collection')` but instead must call `model.collection`. I'm not super fond of the asymmetry but perhaps it's a necessary evil.

Comment: you could do that too - but you'd had to hack parse a bit - so that it wouldn't overide the collection attribute :) - hmm I've got an idea - I'll edit it in :)